# react setState does not update the state us expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that looks like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  incrementQty = () => {
    // calls this.setState({....})
  }

  setQty (qty) => {
    for (....) {
      this.incrementQty()
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that the state does not be updated until the last call in the loop, I knew that setState is asynchronous and I can't use redux here to rerender the component after an action is dispatched.

Has anyone has a solution, and thanks.

Comment: At what context are you calling `setQty`? The `this` object is contingent upon the context. Can you post more code?

Comment: @SeanKwon If the state is updated on the last iteration, that means `this` is correctly bound. It's because `setState` is asynchronous and batches many calls together for efficiency.

Comment: setQty is called from a child component that it's passed to it as a prop

Comment: Why would you need for the incrementQty result be updated _during_ a for loop where you are calling it multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State should be updated as little as possible, if you update quickly within a loop it will cause issues as it tries to re-render based on state change.

If you are updating state based on the current state in 'incrementQty' this will also cause issues as the render cycle has not yet finished and the current state will not be updated on each loop.

To fix this, calculate the new quantity first and then update state:

```js
class MyComponent extends Component {
  setQty (qty) => {
    let newQuantity = 0; //or this.state.quantity?
    for (....) {
      newQuantity++;
    }
    this.setState({quantity:newQuantity}
  }
}
```

P.s. it seems you're passing qty to setQty anyway, are you sure you don't just want to use 'this.setState({quantity:qty});'?

Comment: I'll try the first solution.

Comment: Even that your solution match not exactly my case, it inspired me to find the right choices, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Internal state changing does not happen synchronously, you're right. Any change to internal state is queued up until *at least* after the current function call. So what's happening is your several calls to `setState` are merged into one big increment.

What is it that you need to access state again before a re-render? Rather than just incrementing the quantity, it might be better to just set the quantity initially in component state, rather than using a for loop. If you then want to increment up one value at a time, use the lifecycle methods - perhaps `componentDidUpdate` - to increment a second counter once each render until the correct value for `qty` is reached.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback form of `setState` that is atomic. [Demo](http://codepen.io/tarabyte/pen/peQmwN)
[Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> ```
> this.setState((prevState, props) => {
>   return {myInteger: prevState.myInteger + props.step};
> });
> ```

It updates state kinda "redux" way but w/o redux.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  incrementQty = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
       return {counter: prevState.counter + 1}
    })
  }

  setQty (qty) => {
    for (....) {
      this.incrementQty()
    }
  }
}
```

Full example

```
const { Component } = React
const { render } = ReactDOM


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props, ctx) {
    super(props, ctx);

    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    }

    this.inc = this.inc.bind(this);
    this.dec = this.dec.bind(this);
  }

  // this works for multiple calls
  inc() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        counter: prevState.counter + 1
      }
    })
  }

  // this doesn't work on subsequent calls
  dec() {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter - 1
    })
  }

  up(qty) {   
    while(qty--) {
      this.inc()
    }
  }

  down(qty) {
    while(qty--) {
      this.dec()
    }
  } 

  render() {
    const { counter } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => this.up(10) }>+10</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => this.up(5) }>+5</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.inc}>+</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.dec}>-</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => this.down(5) }>-5</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => this.down(10) }>-10</button>
        </div>

        {counter}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


render(<App />, document.getElementById('content'))
```

Comment: this solution don't resolve my problem because I'am not calculating the new state dependent on the previous state. Thank you!

Comment: @ziedhajsalah Then how you `incrementQty` w/o  using previous state? I mean you need previous value to increment it.

Comment: that's pretty complicated, but in essence, the qty is not in the state instead it's calculated from a list of products